# perl dumper array reading

Tags: arrays, perl

using data:dumper, the XML output shows as below.

```
$VAR1 = {
          'af' => {
                  'minimum' => {
                               'requested_bytes' => '8208'
                             },
                  'time' => [
                            {
                              'lastthreadtid' => '0x0000000030001100',
                              'exclusiveaccessms' => '0.017',
                              'meanexclusiveaccessms' => '0.017',
                              'threads' => '0'
                            },
                            {
                              'totalms' => '41.829'
                            }
                          ],
                  'tenured' => [
                               {
                                 'loa' => {
                                          'freebytes' => '1314816',
                                          'totalbytes' => '1314816',
                                          'percent' => '100'
                                        },
                                 'freebytes' => '1314816',
                                 'totalbytes' => '69219328',
                                 'percent' => '1',
                                 'soa' => {
                                          'freebytes' => '0',
                                          'totalbytes' => '67904512',
                                          'percent' => '0'
                                        }
                               },
                               {
                                 'loa' => {
                                          'freebytes' => '628664',
                                          'totalbytes' => '685056',
                                          'percent' => '91'
                                        },
                                 'freebytes' => '41796952',
                                 'totalbytes' => '68537344',
                                 'percent' => '60',
                                 'soa' => {
                                          'freebytes' => '41168288',
                                          'totalbytes' => '67852288',
                                          'percent' => '60'
                                        }
                               }
                             ],
                  'timestamp' => 'May 01 20:33:51 2016',
                  'intervalms' => '681.342',
                  'refs' => [
                            {
                              'weak' => '19116',
                              'maxSoftReferenceThreshold' => '32',
                              'phantom' => '0',
                              'dynamicSoftReferenceThreshold' => '20',
                              'soft' => '1709'
                            },
                            {
                              'weak' => '18490',
                              'maxSoftReferenceThreshold' => '32',
                              'phantom' => '0',
                              'dynamicSoftReferenceThreshold' => '19',
                              'soft' => '1709'
                            }
                          ],
                  'gc' => {
                          'classunloading' => {
                                              'classes' => '0',
                                              'timevmquiescems' => '0.000',
                                              'timetakenms' => '1.418',
                                              'classloaders' => '0'
                                            },
                          'finalization' => {
                                            'objectsqueued' => '8'
                                          },
                          'timesms' => {
                                       'compact' => '0.000',
                                       'mark' => '39.600',
                                       'sweep' => '0.495',
                                       'total' => '41.787'
                                     },
                          'tenured' => {
                                       'loa' => {
                                                'freebytes' => '628664',
                                                'totalbytes' => '685056',
                                                'percent' => '91'
                                              },
                                       'freebytes' => '41805160',
                                       'totalbytes' => '68537344',
                                       'percent' => '60',
                                       'soa' => {
                                                'freebytes' => '41176496',
                                                'totalbytes' => '67852288',
                                                'percent' => '60'
                                              }
                                     },
                          'intervalms' => '681.373',
                          'type' => 'global',
                          'id' => '24',
                          'totalid' => '24',
                          'contraction' => {
                                           'timetaken' => '0.000',
                                           'amount' => '681984',
                                           'newsize' => '68537344',
                                           'reason' => 'excess free space following gc',
                                           'type' => 'tenured'
                                         }
                        },
                  'type' => 'tenured',
                  'id' => '24',
                  'pending-finalizers' => [
                                          {
                                            'reference' => '0',
                                            'finalizable' => '8',
                                            'classloader' => '0'
                                          },
                                          {
                                            'reference' => '0',
                                            'finalizable' => '8',
                                            'classloader' => '0'
                                          }
                                        ]
                }
        };
```

in the perl code, writing as below throws array error.

```
      print Dumper($dataXML);
       print $dataXML->{af}->{type}.",";
       print $dataXML->{af}->{id}.",";
       print $dataXML->{af}->{timestamp}.",";
       print $dataXML->{af}->{intervalms}.",";
       print $dataXML->{af}->{minimum}->{requested_bytes}.",";
       print $dataXML->{af}->{time}[1]->{totalms}.",";

       print $dataXML->{af}->{tenured}[1]->{freebytes}.",";
       print $dataXML->{af}->{tenured}[1]->{totalbytes}.",";
       print $dataXML->{af}->{tenured}[1]->{percent}.",";
       print $dataXML->{af}->{tenured}[1]->{loa}[1]->{freebytes}.",";
       print $dataXML->{af}->{tenured}[1]->{loa}[1]->{totalbytes}.",";
       print $dataXML->{af}->{tenured}[1]->{loa}[1]->{percent}.",";
       print $dataXML->{af}->{tenured}[1]->{soa}[1]->{freebytes}.",";
       print $dataXML->{af}->{tenured}[1]->{soa}[1]->{totalbytes}.",";
       print $dataXML->{af}->{tenured}[1]->{soa}[1]->{percent}.",";
       print $dataXML->{af}->{tenured}[1]->{freebytes}[2].",";
       print $dataXML->{af}->{tenured}[1]->{totalbytes}[2].",";
       print $dataXML->{af}->{tenured}[1]->{percent}[2].",";
       print $dataXML->{af}->{tenured}[1]->{loa}[2]->{freebytes}.",";
       print $dataXML->{af}->{tenured}[1]->{loa}[2]->{totalbytes}.",";
       print $dataXML->{af}->{tenured}[1]->{loa}[2]->{percent}.",";
       print $dataXML->{af}->{tenured}[1]->{soa}[2]->{freebytes}.",";
       print $dataXML->{af}->{tenured}[1]->{soa}[2]->{totalbytes}.",";
       print $dataXML->{af}->{tenured}[1]->{soa}[2]->{percent}.",";
```

Error:

```
Not an ARRAY reference
```

I have tried multiple ways to get the value of each array key-value, but it only shows the last value.

Comment: Check the Dumper and search for `[` to identify arrays.

Comment: all the places you have `[1]` twice in the same line or `[1]` followed by `[2]`, the second array dereference is on something that isn't an array ref; for loa and soa, it is a has reference, for the other keys, it is a number.

Comment: also, I suspect where you have `{time}[1]` you mean `{time}[0]`.  and likely the you mean the first set of lines for tenured to have `{tenured}[0]` and the next set `{tenured}[1]`

Comment: should i be looping thru to get the hash values, if so how would it be done.

Comment: for which line does it say "Not an ARRAY reference"? would help if you could paste the whole error string here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About your question: The source line number where some error appeared is always good to know as it helps with the solution. For quoted code, it's good to mention which line triggered the error.

Perl knows two common types of references: Array and Hash.

**Arrays** are an ordered list of items. Each item is referenced by a unique, sequential number. Items may be prepended, appended, removed or replaced at the beginning, end or any other position. (See [`unshift`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/unshift.html), [`push`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/push.html), [`shift`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/shift.html), [`pop`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/pop.html), [`splice`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/splice.html) - all of them are clickable links). Arrays commonly use `[ ]`: `$array[0]` addresses the first item and `->[ ]` dereferences an array reference.

**Hashes** are key/value-stores: Each item has a key and a value where both may contain any character and may be of any size. Items are unordered and - because there is no order - can't be prepended or appended. They can be replaced by assigning a new value to an existing key or deleted using [`delete`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/delete.html). `{ }` is used to access hash items and `->{ }` to dereference hash references.

Your code is mixing two styles of dereferencing:

```
   print $dataXML->{af}->{time}[1]->{totalms}.",";
```

Better write:

```
   print $dataXML->{af}->{time}->[1]->{totalms}.",";
```

(Added the `->` between time and `[1]`.) Same for all followup occurrences of `{hashref}[array_index]`. Always using the `->` is more obvious for the reader.

Your error first appears in this line:

```
   print $dataXML->{af}->{tenured}->[1]->{loa}->[1]->{freebytes}.",";
```

As others already outlined in the comments to your question: The value for key `{loa}` is no array reference, but a hash reference. That's why you can't dereference (= access the referenced data structure) it using `->[ ]`. But removing that additional array reference also removes the error:

```
   print $dataXML->{af}->{tenured}->[1]->{loa}->{freebytes}.",";
```

Read more about references at http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html

PS: You always accessed the second item of the arrays within your data structures. This may be what you want, but otherwise remember that Perl arrays are typically zero-based: The first element is `[0]`.